# How to get location by GPS without network in iOS?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I use CoreLocation Framework to get location, when in network it work normal , but when **without the network**, it can not locate always. it will not stop receiving location information after seconds.  **I want to know how to use GPS locating without network**?

Comment: Add some code of your implementation so the anyone can help you.

Comment: It may be because the GPS takes a little longer time to locate.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using your device in a house or building, where the device can't receive GPS satellite signal.

If that's the case, what you are seeing is the expected results. iOS internally keeps the last location (cache). When you start location updates, iOS passes that cashed location quickly to locationManager(:didUpdateLocations). When no network nor satellite signal, no location update will be sent thereafter.

If your device is receiving wifi w/o satellite signal, iOS determines the rough location by using the wifi, and sends location updates. You can't distinguish the source of location updates; they could be from wifi or from GPS satellite. (actually, you can guess by seeing the accuracy. when the source was wifi, accuracy was fixed to 50m w/ my iphone.)

One way to check if your location update is cached or not is to check the time stamp of location update.
The cashed location update should have older time stamp than when you started location update.

So, to your question, you are doing just right thing. Location manager is very easy to use. Try to receive satellite signal in open sky w/o network. For your tests, don't move. It may take 5-7 minutes at most. If you move, it may take longer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Last night, I opened my APP on my way home, when I got home, I got the location information, it may be because the GPS takes a little longer time to locate.Thanks!

Comment: That's good. As I wrote above, w/o network at "cold start", it may take 5-7 minutes. If you have network, your phone gets GPS satellite orbital data called almanac/ephemeris from network to speed up initial location fix. Both data is sent every 30 sec from satellite. So it takes at least 30 sec w/o network at cold start.